# Let UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer override UIPageViewController gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uikit

I'm trying to use a `UIPageViewController` for standard pagination with the Scroll transition style while having an gestures starting from the edge trigger a different action. Currently I'm trying to do this with a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`. However, no matter what I do, the `UIPageViewController`'s gesture recognizer overrides the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, which never gets activated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple gesture recognizers to work simultaneously you have to indicate that by overriding `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` from the `UIGestureRecognizerProtocol`:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This example returns `true` for all gesture recognizers, you can limit/configure the behaviour with the passed parameters.